# Edit margins in res.cls (How to pass through correct value for "margin"?)

Tags: margins, resume, geometry

I'm creating a resumé using the [`res.cls` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=res) and need to make the left and bottom margins smaller. I know I can use e.g. `\topmargin=-0.5in` to decrease the space at the top of the page, but neither `\bottommargin` nor `\leftmargin`, used similarly, have the same effect.

I've also tried `\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}` with no effect (and errors from the keyval package in the TeX log output).

Does anyone know of a way to set the margins for documents created using `res.cls`?

**Edit (09/08):**

I found an [old email thread](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2006-03/msg00357.html) from 2006 that made me go "duh!". Both res.cls and geometry try to handle the `margin` option. I guess I have to somehow send geometry the value instead of the class option, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
foo\par\vfill bar
\end{document}
```

Works for me. Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I'm using the margin option in res.cls, which appears to be what's screwing it up. I updated the question.

Comment: You can use `\makeatletter\def\@classoptionslist{}\makeatother` to clear the class options, but `res.cls` does not play nice with geometry. It was designed for LaTeX 2.09 and copyrighted 1989. You should consider using something a bit newer. CVs and résumés have been discussed on tex.se in several places.

Comment: I have one or two more recent packages to play with, which I can do later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because the problem is solved. Not using res.cls's `margin` option would have fixed it, and switching to the moderncv package has helped immensely. So your answer and comments have been very helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\topmargin=-0.5in
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
```

This worked for me. The first two lines would suffice for your problem.

Comment: This should have been the real answer. +1. I used `\resumewidth = 7.0in` though.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome the margin issue with using the resume document type, I used the following set of options on my one page document:

```
\topmargin=-0.25in
\addtolength{\textwidth}{.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{.5in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
```

However, this will not exactly work on a multiple page document. Perhaps add \evensidemargin as well? Also, note that I didn't use the geometry package because I got an error "No value specified for margin".