# Package keyval Error: No value specified for margin. -- error from geometry

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, resume

I'm using a resume template from the following URL:
(res9b) to be exact.
http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/

The problem is that the resume template doesn't include a header. If I simply
add a new header, the alignment isn't correct. The header overwrites the first line of the page. So I need a way to align the page lower than the footer. I decided to use the geometry package that was recommended here on a similar post.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\def\name{First Last}

\geometry{
    top=0.5in,            
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bottom=0.5in,
    headheight=3ex,      
    headsep=2ex,         
 }

 \pagestyle{myheadings}
 \markright{\name}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 ....
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

```
! Package keyval Error: No value specified for margin.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.848 \ProcessOptionsKV[c]{Gm}
                          %
```

It looks like the problem has something to do with the res.cls file.

```
\documentclass[line,margin]{res}
```

Could that be causing that error somehow? 
How do I fix this error?  I like the format of this resume package and would like to keep it if possible.

Comment: Please note that I just found a duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2778/2975

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global `margin` option is passed to the `geometry` package (like all global options are passed to all packages). And `geometry` needs this option to have an argument.

To fix this either try to add a `margin=<value>` option to the `geometry` package to overwrite the global one or to rename the `margin` option of the class to something else.

Another alternative is to delete the global options, i.e. put the following after the `\documentclass`. The `< >` part marks a place which should be filled out, not taken verbatim.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks! It didn't work when I added it to the geometry package. But when I added margin=<value> to the \documentclass[line,margin=<value>]{res} it did work.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: The statement "To fix this either try to add a margin=<value> option to the geometry package to overwrite the global one" needs correction. `\@classoptionslist` is formed before `\geometry` is encountered. That is why it didn't work for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried another way, and it works quite well! You can download the new `cls` file [here](http://www.lishijian.com/assets/file/res.cls)

Then replace the first line:

```
\documentclass[line,margin]{res}
```

to:

```
\documentclass[line,mm]{res}
```

Then you can use the `geometry` package as you like.

Since the problem is caused by the fact that `geometry` will use global margin too, I renamed the margin option in `res.cls` to `mm`.

Comment: I will put res.cls on that url about 6 hours later.

Comment: `mm` is not a good choice of key name.

Comment: That's true. However, I have tried many meaningful variables, such like `lmargin`, finding that they are still used in geometry.