# "Package xkeyval Error: value `no' is not allowed." while working baposter

Tags: margins, geometry, baposter

I faced the same problem as the author of an older question - I got following message in my log:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: value `no' is not allowed.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.134   }
```

The [linked question's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11214/36834) suggested few options, which I (as a complete LaTeX beginner) didn't understand completely:

> To fix this either try to add a margin= option to the geometry
>   package to overwrite the global one or to rename the margin option of
>   the class to something else.
>
> Another alternative is to delete the global options, i.e. put the
>   following after the \documentclass. The < > part marks a place which
>   should be filled out, not taken verbatim.

```
\makeatletter 
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>} 
\makeatother
```

I tried to add "margin" with some value to the Geometry parameters in baposter.cls, and I tried to add the code in the bottom of the answer citation just after \documentclass in my .tex file (with < > part empty), but no joy here. I didn't found any "global margin option" declared in baposter, though "basemargin" is called many times, so it should be somewhere in the class. How to find it and check any problem that might be there?

What did I misunderstand? And what's more important: what should I do to make baposter work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comments of `baposter.cls` I found:

> ```
> %% 15. September 2011:
> %%     - Merged fork by (rk) back into mainline, essentially taking over all the great improvements that Reinhold Kainhofer coded.
> %%       We call this version 2, as it breaks the interface in some small points. Essentially watch out for this:
> %%       - no/yes keys are now false/true
> ```

Probably you have to replace `no` by `false`.

Comment: The problems started when I updated baposter class, so I suspected something like this, but I missed this point. Anyway, it works now. +1 and accepted.